# PHP: get a list of values by key from a list of dictionary

Tags: php, arrays

```
Array ( 
    [0] => Array (
      [id] => 1 
      [user_id] => 15
      [booked] => 2020-08-01
      [sendin] => 2020-08-03
      [pickup] => 2020-08-08
      [duration] => 5 
    )
    [1] => Array (
      [id] => 2
      [user_id] => 15
      [booked] => 2020-08-01
      [sendin] => 2020-08-03
      [pickup] => 2020-08-08
      [duration] => 5 
    )  
)
```

to get id, by pass in `user_id = 15`, I want

```
$ids = array(1, 2)
```

Is there a shorthand method for this, or do I have to code a function? Appreciate your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`array_filter`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php) to find all the sub-arrays which have `user_id == 15`, and then [`array_map`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php) to extract the corresponding `id` values:

```
$user_id = 15;
$ids = array_map(function ($a) { return $a['id']; },
                 array_filter($array, 
                              function ($a) use ($user_id) {
                                  return $a['user_id'] == $user_id; 
                              })
                 );
print_r($ids);
```

Alternatively, you can use [`array_keys`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-keys.php) to search for the keys of the `user_id` values (extracted by [`array_column`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-column.php)) which are 15 and use those keys in `array_map` to retrieve the `id` values:

```
$ids = array_map(function ($k) use ($array) { return $array[$k]['id']; },
                 array_keys(array_column($array, 'user_id'), $user_id)
                 );
print_r($ids);
```

In both cases the output (for your sample data) is:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 1
    [1] => 2
)
```

[Demo on 3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/XjbvS)

Answer (score 2):

Just wanted to add an alternative answer.  Although the `array_` methods are handy, they also have downsides.  In the other answer, the first method will process the array twice (once for the `array_filter()` and the result with the `array_map()`) and the second method will do this 3 times.  This seems *handy*, but my alternative uses a simple `foreach()` loop.  It makes 1 pass through the array and just checks the user_id and adds it to a list if it matches...

```
$ids = [];
foreach ( $array as $user ) {
    if ( $user['user_id'] == $user_id ) {
        $ids[] = $user['id'];
    }
}
print_r($ids);
```

which gives...

```
Array
(
    [0] => 1
    [1] => 2
)
```